# How much cache can be stored using springboot and Caffeine cache?

Tags: java, spring-boot, caching, caffeine-cache

We have developed an application using Springboot and used Springboot cache as well as Caffeine cache to reduce DB calls and improve performance, But we are thinking cache size may occur problem so kindly help us to know how much cache will work fine?

Note :

1. Server RAM size is 2 GB.
2. Using Kubernetes & Docker
3. Its a small Rest endpoints application, but has some complex task

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your free resources when the project is running on the server and allocate the right amount of free resources to maximum size, do not worry about filling the RAM because there is a recycling strategy that manages when the space is full.

The following article describes the types of strategies:
[Recycling strategy](https://www.programmersought.com/article/25761489222/)